# MS Access Frontend won't Open with an Encrypted Backend

Tags: ms-access, encryption

I'm facing a strange issue in MS Access (2016). When I split my database into a frontend and a backend, and encrypt the backend, my frontend fails to open.

As I open my frontend after splitting the database and encrypting the backend, I should see linked tables, which should not open until I relink them by entering the encryption password. Instead, I'm always taken to Access's 'file open' menu ([Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o55wO.jpg)), as if the frontend never existed! As soon as I decrypt the backend, the frontend starts working normally, displaying the linked tables.

I tried splitting another database downloaded off the internet, and the issue did not occur. So I've singled the issue down to my database file. But I don't have a development background, so I have no idea how to fix it, or what could be going wrong.

There is some VBA code in the database, which is mostly copied off the internet. I tried searching for a similar issue, but with no luck :(.

Please help!

The database files (FE, BE and unsplit) can be downloaded [here](https://1drv.ms/f/s!AoypiDFeCkyJgP5it0jLpF44dl-whg).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just fiddled around and I think I found the answer to solve this issue.

If you have used the code to block the bypass shift key and mouse click to get  access to your  backend database then the following steps will work for you to fix this issue.

Go to your unsplit database and and go to  table view. Then click on All Access Objects Section above the tables and click on option NAVIGATION OPTIONS then tick the boxes "Show hidden objevts " and "Show System Objects"

Now go back to your table list and try to find your hidden table that holds the code to block shift bypass key, in my case my table is cold "UsysRibbons" and then you have to delete it.

Then split your database and you will be able to open your front end database even if your back end database is relocated to other folder.

But if you still want to retain block shift bypass key functionality you have to go to your unsplit database copy  this "UsysRibbons"  table that holds the code to block shift bypass code and paste it to only to your split back end database don't link it to your split front end, and then everything will work as usual.

If this is not the issue why you can't enter your front end when back end is relocated to other folder then you have to look at all of those hidden system tables try to delete them one by one to figure out which table is the parasite table that causes problem.

Good luck to everyone in the future who encounters the same issue.

Thanks